# ¿Por qué el Free Storage Usage en AWS RDS se dispara de un momento a otro?

Tags: aws, amazon-rds

Muchachos buen día.
El día de hoy se me presentó en mi bd oracle el estado "Storage-full" pero no tengo idea de por qué se disparó el evento de un momento a otro, adjunto la imagen del comportamiento de las últimas dos semanas en la cual pueden ver que venía constante pero el día de hoy me quede sin espacio.

A alguno le ha sucedido?

[image: Grafica de free storage usage]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inicialmente tuve este problema luego de hacer una petición que fallaba pero que yo sin saberlo, volvía a replicarla. Seguido a esto se calló mi base de datos en el rds, lo que hice fue reiniciarla pero cuando terminó este proceso el estado era ya "Storage-full". Hago claridad en que la gráfica de la pregunta, refleja el comportamiento de lo que me sucedió, fue en cuestión de minutos que mi almacenamiento se llenó.
Luego de consultar múltiples foros di con varias cosas que me fueron muy útiles para entender qué sucedía y es que a final de cuentas, el espacio físico se puede llenar muy facilmente a punta de logs.
Trataré de ser detallado para que las personas que no tengan mucha idea como lo fue mi caso puedan seguir un paso a paso de lo que deben hacer.

Antes de todo, recomiendo tener una copia de la base de datos y también que aumenten el almacenamiento de la bd almenos en un 10%, esto lo recomiendan en los foros de AWS, primero para que su aplicación no tenga inconvenietes y segundo para quitar el estado de Storage-full.

1) Empecemos por mencionar que necesitaremos usar SQL*PLUS, en mi caso tuve que descargar la [versión 11G de oracle](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/oracle-database-software-downloads.html#19c), en el siguiente enlace pueden encontrar las diferentes versiones.

2) Requerimos [conectarnos a nuestra base de datos](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_ConnectToOracleInstance.html) por medio de SQL*Plus
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Lo resaltado son los datos que debemos introducir, estos datos los obtenemos de nuestra conexión a la bd que se pueden sacar de la conexión del sql developer si lo tienen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
o del rds tal como indican en el enlace anterior
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

3) Una vez ya conectados vamos a consultar el espacio físico que ocupan los archivos temporales.

```
SELECT tablespace_name, file_name, bytes/(1024*1024*1024)  FROM dba_temp_files WHERE tablespace_name like 'TEMP%';

//retorna tablespace_name, nombre del archivo y el tamaño ocupado en gigas
//A nosotros nos importa el tamaño y el tablespace_name dado que el primero nos confirma 
//si ahí está nuestro problema y el segundo se usa para el siguiente paso
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

4)Ahora resta seguir los pasos que indica [Philip Schlump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1824572/how-to-shrink-temp-tablespace-in-oracle) en la primer respuesta del post del enlace, el cuál tiene todos los créditos por su respuesta, es la más completa que he logrado encontrar, así que le agradezco mucho.

Y listo con los dos primeros pasos que él indica debería de bastar, de lo contrario es necesario que sigan el último que es crear un nuevo tablespace.

Antes de hacer esto en mi caso reinicié mi instancia rds y luego apliqué los pasos que él indica porque me estaba saliendo un error: "ora-03297 el archivo contiene datos utilizados más allá del valor resize solicitado" el cual se debe a que hay archivos temporales que están siendo usados.

Bueno espero les sea útil.